# SQL - Primary Key autoincrement without Identity seed or a Sequence

Tags: sql-server

I want contiguous sequence of numbers as Primary Key. But I don't want to use Identity Seed or a Sequence for some reasons.

Following is my code

```
Insert Into Items (ItemId, ItemName)
Values((Select MAX(ItemId)+1 from Items), 'Some Name')
```

This works fine when there are some rows in the Table. But when There aren't any rows in the table *Items*, MAX(itemId) gives NULL.

I want MAX(itemId) to give 0 when there aren't any rows.

Comment: You could also handle this with a computed column or a trigger.

Comment: @TabAlleman that would further complicate the problem, as I am using this database in my C# Application

Comment: Why do you not want to use what works? Any time you try to roll your own identity type of column you are going to have issues with concurrency. An identity is perfectly suited for this type of thing.

Comment: Identity is not always contagious. There are several issues related to Identity seed, in SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of these two ways will work:

```
Insert Into Items (ItemId, ItemName)
Values(COALESCE((Select MAX(ItemId)+1 from Items), 0), 'Some Name')
```

or

```
Insert Into Items (ItemId, ItemName)
Values(ISNULL((Select MAX(ItemId)+1 from Items), 0), 'Some Name')
```

`COALESCE` returns its first non-NULL argument. `ISNULL` returns the second argument if the first is NULL.

Comment: This mostly works, but concurrency is a real issue with this type of code.